# grep combine -f and -E

Tags: grep

I want to combine the content of a patter file with a regular expressions, i.e. grep -E -f.

The input file has the format

```
2   List_of_anthropologists<!!>Q1279970
3   List_of_Governors_of_Alabama<!!>Q558677
2027476 12th_Dalai_Lama<!!>Q25240
etc..
```

and the pattern file has the format:

```
13th_Dalai_Lama
5th_Dalai_Lama
etc...
```

I can make it work by manually putting in the pattern "13th_Dali_Lama"

```
grep -E  "^(\d*)(?:\t)13th_Dalai_Lama" input_file
```

But how to I combine the -f option so that 13th_Dalai_Lama is replace by the lines in the pattern file?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The output should be the lines in the input_file that match the regex, having the lines in the pattern file inserted "^(\d*)(?:\t)line from pattern file". For example: 13th_Dalai_Lama should match:  13th_Dalai_Lama<!!>Q558677 but not List_of_13th_Dalai_Lama<!!>Q558677

Comment: Your pattern file contains no substring from your input file.

Comment: The input file contains 4M entries, the example didn't include it, but yes, for example: 2051526 5th_Dalai_Lama<!!>Q25252 is in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep, GNU sed and bash:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/.*/\\b&\\b/' pattern_file) input_file
```